# writing in html file with php on IIS

Tags: php, file, iis, file-writing

I am trying to write in a html file with php. The code is working fine on for example XAMPP Apache. Now I am trying to get it to run on IIS.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

$handle = fopen("feedback_tracker.html", "a");
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   fwrite($handle, "<hr>");
   
   fwrite($handle, "<br>");
 foreach($_POST as $value) {

  fwrite ($handle, $value . "<br>");

 }
 fwrite($handle, "<br>");
  fwrite($handle, $date);
 
 
 fclose($handle);



?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p Style="font-size: 20pt">Die Nachricht wurde erfolgreich übermittelt!</p>
<br>
<p Style="font-size: 15pt">weiterleitung erfolgt...</p>
<script>


    setTimeout(function () {
        history.go(-2);
    }, 4000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I installed php on the IIS and now the site it getting opend and displayed correctly(I can see the html content of the php file). However somehow the input of a textarea on another site is getting called with a normal form action, but is not getting written in the "feedback_tracker.html"like it should and like it worked already on XAMPP. 
Do I have to install something additional on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the issue with the permissions of the file "feedback_tracker.html".

Right click on the file, select properties, select security , edit the permissions and grant full access to all the users and check if it works.